# Parsing data bug

Tags: php, json

I have the following code:

```
$_REQUEST[ 'LOM' ]
var_dump($_REQUEST[ 'LOM' ]);
```

the result is the following JSON:

```
{
   "id":0,
   "type":"root",
   "related_dropzone_id":0,
   "related_dropzone_order":0,
   "children":{
      "1376071054231":{
         "id":"1376071054231",
         "type":"section",
         "related_dropzone_id":0,
         "related_dropzone_order":1,
         "dropzones":{
            "A":1376071054231
         },
         "options":{

         },
         "children":{
            "1376071056267":{
               "id":"1376071056267",
               "type":"section",
               "related_dropzone_id":1376071054231,
               "related_dropzone_order":0,
               "dropzones":{
                  "A":1376071056267
               },
               "options":{

               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

but when using the "correct" following code:

```
$result = json_decode($_REQUEST[ 'LOM' ]);
var_dump($result);  // the result is NULL
```

Why it doesn't convert the JSON into an array?

I tested this way but not work:

```
$result = json_decode( "'" . $_REQUEST[ 'LOM' ] . "'");
var_dump($result);  // the result is NULL
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://3v4l.org/03n6i

Comment: I've also tried, works for me :/ http://codepad.org/swbHZjdN

Comment: look at magic_quotes setting on the host... this is probably what is screwing you up .

Comment: The problem is with $_REQUEST['LOM'], i copy and paste de "the result is the following JSON:" intro $result = json_decode( 'here' ); and work.

Comment: Stray characters? UTF-8 BOM somewhere, unprintable characters at any place, those are the suspects, look at your output in a hex editor.

Comment: [if you run your original `$_REQUEST['LOM']` through this code](http://codepad.org/Cq9jUZl3), we may be able to say more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @merdincz.

I solved with following code:

```
var_dump( json_decode( str_replace( '\\', '', $_REQUEST[ 'LOM' ] ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$so=$_REQUEST[ 'LOM' ];
json_decode( $so, true, 9 )
    $json_errors = array(
        JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error has occurred',
        JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded',
        JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
        JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
    );
echo 'Last error : ', $json_errors[json_last_error()], PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
```

first try this code if you taking Syntax error may this helps you;

```
$so = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $_REQUEST[ 'LOM' ]);
```

Comment: @josecarlos, so you can try 
`$so = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $_REQUEST[ 'LOM' ]);
var_dump(json_decode($so));`

Comment: i tried and the result is NULL again. I Continue with error :-(